# xorg.conf.d not loaded when starting X while docked

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, thinkpad, dock

Recently installed archlinux on a Lenovo T530 Thinkpad and using it with a Mini dock Series 3. Docking and undocking works just like it should, using acpid to execute scripts turning screens on and off, but if I start X while the computer is docked it appears to not load the `xorg.conf.d` files that I have, such as setting the proper keymap. It also makes both the built in and external screen use an unmotivated low resolution.

What could be the problem? Is there any known solutions to this?

(Connected to the dock is a bluetooth mouse, a bluetooth keyboard and a DVI-display. The linux distribution installed is Arch.)